# git archive error "fatal: pathspec 'Working Report/RPT0057/RPT0057_sub_succ1.jrxml' did not match any files"

Tags: git, archive

when I run the command git archive, it return error "fatal: pathspec 'Working Report/RPT0057/RPT0057_sub_succ1.jrxml' did not match any files' , why?

I google and some said this error is still to the file is untracked, but my case seems is not about this problem, the result of git status as paste as follow:

```
PS D:\kei_D\CMIS_DEV\CMIS> git status

Refresh index: 100% (7440/7440), done.
On branch Phase2_20190523
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Phase2_20190523'.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/Content/Scripts/ReportParameterPopup.js
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/Content/Scripts/minifiedReportParameterPopup.js
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/Controllers/ReportController.cs
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/DEVB_CMIS.csproj.user
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/Web.config
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/export/RPT0076B.xls
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/export/auto_run.xls
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS/export/perf.txt
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.ContractPaymentResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.ContractResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.ConvictionResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.ConvictionResource.zh.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.RCPResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.ReportResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.UserInfoResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.UserInfoResource.zh.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.UserRegistrationResource.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/DEVB.CMIS.TextResources.UserRegistrationResource.zh.resources
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed/Models/CMISModel.csdl
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed/Models/CMISModel.msl
    modified:   Source/DEVB_CMIS_Business/obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed/Models/CMISModel.ssdl
    modified:   Source/Mail.Notes/obj/Debug/Mail.Notes.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
    deleted:    Source/export/RPT0076B.xls
    deleted:    Source/export/auto_run.xls
    deleted:    Source/export/perf.txt
    modified:   Working Report/RPT0076B/RPT0076B.jrxml

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Source/DEVB_CMIS/Template/auto_run.xlsm
    Source/DEVB_CMIS/Web.config.bak
    Source/DEVB_CMIS/export/abc.xlsm
    Source/DEVB_CMIS/export/perf__20190626150933290.txt
    Source/DEVB_CMIS/export/testing.xlsm
    Working Report/One_off_script_p2/20190621/
    Working Report/RPT0055/
    test2.zip

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
PS D:\kei_D\CMIS_DEV\CMIS>
```

the archive command is as follow:

```
PS D:\kei_D\CMIS_DEV\CMIS> git archive --output=test2.zip HEAD $(git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only 52006e13..3686dd94)
fatal: pathspec 'Working Report/RPT0057/RPT0057_sub_succ1.jrxml' did not match any files
PS D:\kei_D\CMIS_DEV\CMIS>
```

Comment: changed, paste code and result now

Comment: You compared commits `52006e13` and `3686dd94`. For any file that was in `52006e13` but not in `3686dd94`, you told Git to copy that file from `HEAD` and put it into `test2.zip`. Why do you believe that files that are not in `3686dd94` (but are in `52006e13`) are necessarily in `HEAD`? Git says that at least one such file is not in `HEAD`.

Comment: @torek oh, yes, RPT0057_sub_succ1.jrxml is deleted in later commit 3686dd94, then how to modify my previous command?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you intend to achieve. `git archive` writes an archive file containing either every file from a specified commit (such as `HEAD`), or selected files from a specified commit. Pick a commit and, if you like, specify some files that are in that commit, and you'll get an archive based on that commit.

Comment: @torek I want to writes an archive file containing a range of past old commit (e.g. from commit 52006e13 to commit 3686dd94), but commit 3686dd94 is not the latest commit, and some files between 52006e13 and 3686dd94 may be deleted after 3686dd94.

Comment: Archive files, by their nature, *cannot* contain a range of commits. Each commit represents a snapshot of files, so a range of commits is not a single archive, but rather *many* archives. For instance, if there are 10 commits in your range, you could write 10 archives, one for each commit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195672/discussion-between-user1169587-and-torek).

Comment: Oops: I didn't notice that the diff filter letter was lowercase `d` rather than uppercase `D`. So the `git diff` produces files that *weren't* deleted in the single diff produced here. But clearly some files were deleted afterward.